# Can an html input element with a type of time have a default value?

Tags: html, forms

Should the following code work to set a default time? If not, is there a way to make it work strictly with html and no Javascript?

```
<input type="time" name="time" id="whatever" value="1:10">
```

When I manually set a time to the widget and use document.getElementById("whatever").value to output the value I get a string that uses military time to denote am/pm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HH:MM` format, so:

```
<input type="time" name="time" id="whatever" value="13:10">
```

for `1PM` or:

```
<input type="time" name="time" id="whatever" value="01:10">
```

for `1AM`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bSCMg/)**

Comment: I see, I simply omitted the 0

Comment: You need to use `HH:MM` format. Currently you're using `H:MM` format.

Comment: I was getting an incorrect date for `HH:MM`. Using `HH:mm` worked for me.